# Why aren’t my timestamps displayed in users local timezone

Tags: slack-api

The following JSON is sent, as the “attachments” argument, in a call to the `chat.postMessage` API method.  The message is posted to an individual user (not a shared channel) and per documentation I was expecting the timestamps to be displayed in the target user’s local timezone.  Instead they are always displayed in UTC, so am I doing something wrong?

```
[
  {
    "mrkdwn_in": [
      "text"
    ],
    "title": "Important alert",
    "footer": "MyCodeThing",
    "fallback": "Important alert summary",
    "text": "A thing with a date just happened <!date^1475148495^{date_short_pretty} at {time}|Sep 29 at 09:28 PM UTC>\n\nUsers Name from *Company & Associates*",
    "fields": [
      {
        "short": false,
        "title": "",
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "short": false,
        "title": "Device",
        "value": "Using Chrome on Other."
      }
    ],
    "footer_icon": "https://anysite.domain.com/static/img/image_only_16.png",
    "color": "#f54b0a"
  }
]
```

Comment: I was not aware that Slack has the ability to show time in the correct format for the current user, except for the `ts` item in attachments. Cool

Comment: Do you know if the target user has a timezone set? If they haven't explicitly specified a timezone, it's possible Slack is assuming UTC.

Comment: @TaylorSingletary yes, the target users I was testing against all seemed to have their timezone specified correctly (via Profile & Account → Timezone)

Comment: I tested this and can reproduce the behavior. Somehow always the fallback is shown, not the user-specific time. Also, when I use the `text` part in another attachment it works fine. This looks like a bug to me. Would file a bug report.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken did you filed the bug? did you receive any help from slack about it?

Comment: @diegueus9 no, its not my issue. was suggestion to markhellewell to submit a burg report

Answer (score 1):

Based on the official docs (as of 2023), it is unfortunately the expected behaviour that the messages will always be time stamped with the **computer's time zone** instead of the user's time zone set in the "Language & region" preferences.

> Note: When you update your time zone in Slack, your reminders and notification schedule will stay in your local time. Your messages will always be time stamped with your computer's time zone.

Ref: https://slack.com/intl/en-au/help/articles/219889247-Manage-your-time-zone-preferences#desktop-1

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though it completely ignores the timezone in the preferences, and it shows the time in the current timezone for the PC it is running on.  Which, in my case, is UTC.  I can change the timezone preference in slack to whatever I want, but it comes up UTC on the computer where I have this problem.

I can use the same account, open the same chat history on another PC, and it shows it in the correct time according to that PC's OS.

This is in the app, not the browser version.  I don't know the behavior of the browser version.